# Does not update application with service worker

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have an application developed in Angular with Node.js, I use Firebase hosting since my application works with various Firebase services.

I made implementations for my application to become Angular Progressive Web Application (PWA), the implementations I made are identical to the content I found in this [Angular Progressive Web Application](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/installable-angular-progressive-web-app/).

**So when I run the command:**

```
npm run pwa && firebase deploy --only hosting
```

I could see that the moment I finish deploying my application, when I access the URL of my application, the changes you make are not detected.

For changes to be made after deploying changes, I need to go to **DevTools** from the browser and go to **Application > Clear Storage > Clear Site Data**.

I would like to update my application the moment I deploy without having to do the above procedure for the changes to be made in my application.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: When a previously used PWA loads, it uses what is in the cache. And updates to the newest version in the background. When the user then closes the PWA and opens again, then they should see the changes.

Comment: But does this only happen if I close Chrome? Or if I close the tab that was open the application and reopen the update occurs too?

Comment: Probably just the tab. But I am not sure. You will have to test to confirm.

Comment: Well after doing some tests I realized that it is not updating, including the icons that I changed in the `manifest.json` did not update. It only updates when I run **Clear Site Data** in **DevTools**.

Comment: While testing - Do as you have been doing. Realistically will you be updating your manifest often (at all) once you are done with your app? If so, you may want to search "updating PWA manifest"

Comment: I've already noticed that it refreshes in the background, but this is not always the case ... should occur whenever I perform the `firebase deploy --only hosting` command.

Comment: Is not the manifest updating itself when detected changes? Does the browser detect changes by itself?

Comment: Make sure you configure firebase hosting to not cache the service workers file.

Comment: and how do I know if the firebase is not configured to store?